# Take screenshot using php

Tags: php, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of my site on click of button.
I use following code.It shows some error.Please correct this code.

```
?php 
  $browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application"); 
  $handle = $browser->HWND; 
  $browser->Visible = true; 
  $browser->Fullscreen = true; 
  $browser->Navigate("http://www.google.com"); 

  while ($browser->Busy) { 
      com_message_pump(4000); 
  } 
  $im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0); 
  $browser->Quit(); 
  imagepng($im, "google_screenshot.png"); 
  imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

errors are:
1. Warning: imagegrabwindow() expects parameter 1 to be long
2. Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource
3. Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Check the value of $handle, my guess is that it isn't an integer. Is Internet Explorer being opened successfully?

Comment: @JackFrankland value nof $handle is 197000 and IE is open successfully